# C# controller support without XNA or DirectX

Tags: c#, windows, gamecontroller

I'm trying to build a Windows game without the now sunset XNA or DirectX, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to create controller support (mostly just XBox controllers). Is there anything in the standard C# libraries? If at all possible, I want to avoid using any external libraries or anything.

Comment: You could use SlimDx, it has support for XInput, which would be what you are looking for.

Comment: I would suggest looking at SharpDX which is actively maintained and just had a new version coming out

Comment: I believe monogame supports Xbox 360 controllers.

Comment: If you were using Linux this would be an option: https://github.com/nahueltaibo/gamepad

Comment: If you are willing to target Win10+ you can use Windows.Gaming: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3N0d6ZMNvOY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, without using XInput DLLs, you cannot access/work with XBox 360 controllers. You can either [PInvoke XInput](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492473/Using-XInput-to-access-an-Xbox-Controller-in-M) dlls directly or work with it through SlimDX (as suggested in the comments).

AFAIK, [XInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405051(v=vs.85).aspx) has not been deprecated. You can use XInput on Windows 8 with Store apps and I believe I've seen this DLL even on the Windows 10 preview.